# What part of speech is "touch" in the phrase "sense of touch"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

Is it just a noun, or is there a more precise name? It seems like an object of the preposition, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's a noun.  A noun, as the song goes, is a person, place, or thing, and *touch* is certainly a thing.

In this sentence, it is the object of the preposition *of*, but the the object of preposition is always a noun-phrase of one sort or another (e.g. a noun, a pronoun, something like that).

Comment: _Touch_ is a **thing**? Where can you buy it? What does it look like? That's not the definition of a noun. Luckily, you do point out that only a noun phrase can be the object of a preposition; **that** is a correct definition.

Comment: @JohnLawler - "Love" is a thing, but [Can't buy me love](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/beatles/cantbuymelove.html).

Comment: It's a noun all right. But it's not a thing. It's an abstraction, like diagonalization of a matrix. The point is that "person, place, or thing" is what you tell third-graders when they ask what a noun is. It makes them shut up and it sound good. But it doesn't describe nouns; it just picks out some examples. Persons, places, and things are indeed represented by nouns; but they are very far from being the only things represented.

Comment: @JohnLawler -- I think your sense that "thing" necessarily means a tangible thing, like an apple or office building.  Are things like Wednesday, injustice, memory, voltage, efficiency, love, history, proximity, and notoriety not "things" in your vocabulary?  (Remember, "thing" originally meant "royal court", then "legal case", two not-very-tangible, uh, things.)

Comment: So if all those are things, how do you tell them from adjectives and verbs? Just by knowing they're nouns?

Comment: @JohnLawler -- I don't know if I can give a _helpful_ answer, but I know they are things, because they are... things.  They are independent concepts that can be modified, can act, can have other things act upon them.  And all things are nouns.  Distinguishing them from verbs is easy: a verb is a noun in action.  Almost any noun can be an adjective and (to a lesser extent) vice versa.  There is Wednesday morning, voltage drop, history class; in the other direction, there is _The Red And The Black_, an unnerving quiet, _The Quick and the Dead_ and so on.

Comment: If they can act, they're verbs. And what noun is in action in _It's a long way to Tipperary_ or _It's too hot to move_? Seriously, what they told you in grade school is not what you want to base an adult analysis on. Have a look at a real book about language, like (say) Frawley's _Linguistic Semantics_ (1992 Erlbaum). It has a chapter on "Entities", which is what nouns refer to, and points out that "person, place, and thing" have the definition backwards. Here's [the chapter outline](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/frawleyentities.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler, if you are hoping for a totalizing theory of grammar, you are going to be disappointed.  You see *It is hot.* and ask, "Who is 'being' in that sentence?" The obvious answer is "it".  My question would be, what is "it"?  Grammar is impossible -- but easy compared to semantics.

Comment: Merely a consistent one, which gives syntactic tests for syntactic labels, and semantic tests for semantic labels. Not semantic tests for syntactic labels. That makes semantics and syntax both easy, as long as you are careful not to mix them up unnecessarily.

Comment: Syntactic tests for syntactic labels?  Never happening: "<Noun> flies like a <noun>."